# Other than DB setup and connection, Is there any other differences while using MySQL instead of SQLite3 in Django?

Tags: mysql, django

By difference I mean, like the DB queries. For example for a login/registration in PHP/MySQL, you need to store them and check the credentials via MySQL queries in PHP right?

Similarly **is there any MySQL specific codes** required here?

*Pardon me if I have structured the question wrongly. I am new to Django and I started learning it yesterday.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is - No. Usually with Django you communicate with its built in Django ORM, which in most usual cases performs perfectly. Using ORM you use Python syntax, not SQL. But also there might be some specific cases, which are not yet implemented with ORM - so you can write a query in Raw SQL.

And only here comes the MySQL specific features (I guess also some ORM features might not be working at 100%, but that will be clearly noticed in ORM documentation - that is caused by that Django is mostly designed to interact with PostgreSQL).  
P.S. Sorry that I does not apply any useful links to this answer - I am posting this through Android app and it is so wired here in formatting answers :/